# RoboBuilder HUNO Simulation in C#

Tags: c#, 3d, simulation, robotics-studio

I have this question about RoboBuilder, do you guys ever heard about it?
If you haven't, try to visit the website, robobuilder.net

I am a beginner in C#, unfortunately i have to deal with it, to create simulation model of the HUNO(humanoid) robot.

**The question is, does C# capable of creating a custom 3D independently? Of course in this case, a model of a humanoid robot.**

The C# will be later integrated with the Microsoft Robotic Developer Studio (MRDS). It will be simulated in that environment.

Any comment will be really helpful.
Thanks.

Comment: what i meant by custom 3D, is creating our own 3D shape, in this case, i am trying to create a robot shape.

Answer (score 0):

[WPF supports 3D](http://www.wpftutorial.net/IntroductionTo3D.html). You can also use [DirectX in .NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Managed_DirectX). I hope this answers your rather vague question.